# Relationship between power of incandescent lightbulb and illuminance

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits

I have recently performed and analysed an experiment and I am currently stuck on making sense of the outcome. Any help would be much appreciated.

The experiment consists of a simple DC voltage source in series with two resistors and a small incandescent lightbulb. The idea was to simply vary the voltage and the resistor values, and to measure the illuminance of the lightbulb. So, three inputs and one output. The measuring of the illuminance was done with a luxmeter, which was kept at the same distance throughout the experiment. A certain statistical design (Two Level Full Factorial design) was kept in mind for the experiment. This allowed for an Analysis of Variance to be done, which tells you whether or not an input has a significant effect on the value of the output. In this case you would expect all inputs to be significant,  such a conclusion was indeed drawn during the analysis. The design also allows for an equation to be summoned, which is where the problem arises. If necessary I can give the equation in full, but *the current interpretation is that the illuminance (better: lux) is proportional to the power of the lightbulb squared. Or rather, voltage of DC source to the fourth.*

Yet, I would expect illuminance to be proportional to power instead of power squared. I am having trouble backing up this outcome with evidence, **physics wise**. What I am asking from you is to lead me to the right information or to offer more direct help. My own googling has had an adverse effect.

My gratitude for at least reading this.

EDIT: If there is any possibility it *is* correct, please let me know. Until that moment though, I conclude my experiment was simply improperly designed and the outcome is somewhat nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between irradiance and illuminance. Irradiance power/cm$^2$/steradian. Illuminance is the same, except the power is weighted by eye response. E.G. Power in the infrared contributes nothing, red contributes some, green contributes more. As the voltage drops, the filament cools, and the spectrum shifts toward the infrarad.

EDIT: Your experiment isn't nonsense. You just have to figure out the spectrum of the filament, and how the standard photopic response curve weights that spectrum.

For the filament, you could measure the spectrum. Or assuming it emits BlackBody radiation is a good approximation. You would need to know the temperature of the filament. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

For the eye response, photopic vision is daytime vision, scotopic vision is night time vision. They use different receptors. Many measurements of eye response have been done, and the results have been organized into a standard photopic eye response curve. You can start reading here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function.

You can get data and links to more articles here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/efficacy.html

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly I should use $\phi_v=683.002\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \bar{y}(\lambda)\phi_e(\lambda)d\lambda$ wherein $\phi_e(\lambda)$ can be approximated by assuming the incandescent lightbulb behaves as a black body. For each possible temperature of the lightbulb (temperature changes as voltage over filament changes) I can then find the luminous flux, and as such I can combine all information to find how luminous flux changes as temperature (i.e. voltage) of the filament changes.